# Could not find generator spree_simple_sales:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator, spree

I am following the [spree extension tutorial](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html) and am getting

*Could not find generator spree_simple_sales:install*.  when I try to install that though I followed every step.

Also When I try install the 'spree_fancy' I get *Could not find generator spree_fancy:install*

Gems included by the bundle:

- actionmailer (3.2.14)
- actionpack (3.2.14)
- active_utils (2.0.1)
- activemerchant (1.38.1)
- activemodel (3.2.14)
- activerecord (3.2.14)
- activeresource (3.2.14)
- activesupport (3.2.14)
- acts_as_list (0.2.0)
- arel (3.0.2)
- awesome_nested_set (2.1.5)
- aws-sdk (1.14.1)
- bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
- bigdecimal (1.1.0)
- builder (3.0.4)
- bundler (1.1.4)
- cancan (1.6.10)
- canonical-rails (0.0.3)
- capybara (2.1.0)
- childprocess (0.3.9)
- climate_control (0.0.3)
- cocaine (0.5.2)
- coffee-rails (3.2.2)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
- database_cleaner (1.1.1)
- deface (0.9.1)
- devise (2.2.7)
- devise-encryptable (0.1.2)
- diff-lcs (1.2.4)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (2.0.2)
- factory_girl (4.2.0)
- ffaker (1.19.0)
- ffi (1.9.0)
- highline (1.6.18)
- hike (1.2.3)
- httparty (0.11.0)
- i18n (0.6.5)
- journey (1.0.4)
- jquery-rails (3.0.4)
- jquery-ui-rails (4.0.5)
- json (1.8.0)
- kaminari (0.14.1)
- mail (2.5.4)
- mime-types (1.25)
- money (5.1.1)
- multi_json (1.8.1)
- multi_xml (0.5.5)
- nokogiri (1.5.10)
- orm_adapter (0.4.0)
- paperclip (3.4.2)
- paranoia (1.3.1)
- polyamorous (0.6.4)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- rabl (0.8.4)
- rack (1.4.5)
- rack-cache (1.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.3)
- rack-test (0.6.2)
- rails (3.2.14)
- railties (3.2.14)
- rake (10.1.0)
- ransack (1.0.0)
- rdoc (3.12.2)
- rspec-core (2.14.5)
- rspec-expectations (2.14.3)
- rspec-mocks (2.14.3)
- rspec-rails (2.14.0)
- rubyzip (0.9.9)
- sass (3.2.12)
- sass-rails (3.2.6)
- select2-rails (3.4.9)
- selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
- simplecov (0.7.1)
- simplecov-html (0.7.1)
- spree_api (2.0.5)
- spree_auth_devise (2.0.0 b30f87d)
- spree_backend (2.0.5)
- spree_core (2.0.5)
- spree_frontend (2.0.5)
- spree_simple_sales (2.0.4)
- sprockets (2.2.2)
- sqlite3 (1.3.8)
- state_machine (1.2.0)
- stringex (1.5.1)
- thor (0.18.1)
- tilt (1.4.1)
- treetop (1.4.15)
- truncate_html (0.9.2)
- tzinfo (0.3.37)
- uuidtools (2.1.4)
- versioncake (1.0.0)
- warden (1.2.3)
- websocket (1.0.7)
- xpath (2.0.0)

What did I miss ?

Comment: Please show us your `Gemfile` so we can see where you're getting spree_simple_sales from.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why you're getting that error for spree_simple_sales, but I can tell you why you're seeing it for spree_fancy: that gem is not included in that list you have provided.